# objective c shortcut in assigning values to a class property

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I'm not sure if I used the correct terms, please understand I just started experimenting with objective yesterday and I came from a c# background so I might use some c# terms.

With that said. I have two classes. 1 main class which uses the other class as a property:

```
@class Fighter;
@interface Match : NSObject{
    int Id;
    Fighter *Fighter;
    int FScore;
}
@property int Id, FScore;
@property Fighter *Fighter;

@end
```

*implementation:

```
@implementation Match
@synthesize Id, FScore, Fighter;    
@end
```

This is the class referenced:

```
@interface Fighter : NSObject{
    int Id;
    NSString *Name;
}
@property int Id;
@property NSString *Name;
@end


@implementation Fighter
@synthesize Id, Name;
@end
```

Now this is how I would create an instance of the object

```
@autoreleasepool {

        // insert code here...
        NSLog(@"Hello, World!");

        Match *match = [[Match alloc]init];
        match.Id = 1;
        match.Fighter = [[Fighter alloc]init];
        match.Fighter.Id = 9;
        match.Fighter.Name = @"womp";
    }
```

Now, I was wondering if there's like a shortcut in assigning the values for the Fighter instance. As in c# you can do something like so:

```
match.Fighter = new Fighter{ Id = 9, Name = "womp" };
```

Wanted to know just in case I may add several more properties to that class or to any other class.

PS.

Is it better to use [[Class alloc] init] than [Class new]??

Thanks!!!

Comment: Property & Variable names should start with lower case in obj-c. Please don't use C# naming conventions in obj-c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way to do this in Objective-C is to create a custom `-init` method with arguments for properties to be initialized. So you might have a `-[Fighter initWithID:name:]` method:

```
- (id)initWithID:(NSInteger)id name:(NSString *)name
{
    self = [self init];
    if (self) {
        self.ID = id;
        self.name = name;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Then you create your fighter object with:

```
match.fighter = [[Fighter alloc] initWithID:9 name:@"womp"];
```

A couple comments on your code. In Objective-C it is convention to begin property names with a lowercase letter. The exception is if the name of the property is an acronym like 'ID' or 'URL', in which case you make it all uppercase. This same is true of method and variable names. Capitalized names are reserved for types including class names (e.g. 'Fighter').

Regarding your P.S. question, `+new` just calls alloc then init and returns the result, so they're exactly equivalent. That said, +new is not really commonly used among Objective-C programmers, and you'll see alloc/init used *much* more frequently.

Finally, assuming you're deploying to a target using the modern Objective-C runtime (10.6+ and 64-bit) you don't need to explicitly declare instance variables to back your @properties, because the compiler will synthesize (create) them for you. With recent versions of Xcode (4.4 and higher), you don't even need the @synthesize statements, because the compiler will insert those for you too. The @property statement is all you need.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks so much for the detailed reply. Follow up question regarding the auto synthesize,do u mean i still have to do @property but can omit the @synthesize? Cuz when I tried that on my Match class it would say "Authosynthesized property FScore will use syntesized instance variable _FScore, ....." and would fail my compile. EDIT: my bad, it's a warning, not error

Comment: With Xcode 4.4+, the compiler will automatically insert the `@synthesize` statement at compile time. So, you are correct that you still need the @property statement, but you can omit `@synthesize`. Regarding the warning, when Xcode auto generates an `@synthesize` statement, it creates an instance variable whose name is the property name prefixed with an underscore. I believe you're getting a warning because you've explicitly declared an ivar with a different name and the compiler wants you to know that that ivar is *not* going to be used in the (synthesized) property accessor methods.

Comment: awesome, so should i just ignore those warnings?

Comment: No, you should remove the explicit instance variable declarations in your `@interface` section. That is, delete the stuff contained in the braces ({}) right after `@interface Fighter : NSObject`. You should never ignore warnings.

Comment: that worked. So when do I use instance variables in obj c? I'm used to using instance vars in c# specially when calculating values and storing data when waiting for transactions. Also, why do you use "id" as the return type? and not the instance of the class or void? eg: - (id)initWithID:

Comment: Synthesized `@properties` are still backed by instance variables, it's just that they're created for you by the compiler. It's become fairly uncommon to declare your own ivars, but it's only actually relatively recently that the compiler started doing it for you. Previously, even for `@properties` (which also haven't been around forever), you always had to explicitly declare them. You still *can*, there's just not usually a need. In your case, the warning was actually because your ivar names didn't match the autosynthesized names. You could also have prepended the names with an underscore.

Comment: The second part of your comment (why return `id`?) probably deserves its own new question.

Comment: made it! and thanks for your time. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13369012/objective-c-classes-why-return-id-instead-of-its-own-class