# objective c classes why return -(id) instead of it's own class

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I came from a C# background where you initialize a class and then return itself like so

```
public class MyClass{
  public int Id;
  public string Name;
}

MyClass classInstance = new MyClass();
:
:
```

I know c# is different from objective c, but I'm trying to find a way to easily understand how objective c works to make the transition easier. And figure out best practices too.

Anyway, my question is why doyou have to create a method and return an "id" instead of returning it's own type? Like so:

```
- (id)initWithID:(NSInteger)id name:(NSString *)name
{
    self = [self init];
    if (self) {
        self.ID = id;
        self.name = name;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: Your question was answered in  this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612919/in-objective-c-why-is-id-used-as-return-type-for-init-methods

Comment: i did saw that one already but it didn't make sense to me. i think that posting a new question made it easier for me to another. apologies if it wasted space but it still helped me.

Comment: No problem. Maybe the reference can help others.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You return an object of type `id` in initialization methods because of inheritance.

Think of it this way: You have an object of class `Foo`. It has an init method called `initWithWidgets`. Now, you create a subclass of `Foo` and name it `Bar`. By the rules of inheritance, it has access to the `initWithWidgets` method. If the return type for `initWithWidgets` was `Foo`, then your `Bar` class would be unable to use it to initialize itself! The return type would be different than the object you are trying to instantiate. Thus, if you use `id`, you're saying "the return type of this object can be of any type" and you're safe for the subclasses!

Comment: i see, now that makes sense! for the record i did see an answered question from a different link i just had a hard time understanding it. this makes more sense imo. thanks again

Answer (score 4):

When a method returns an object of type `id`, it means the object could be of any type. For example, if you declare an `NSMutableArray`, you do this:

```
NSMutableArray *someArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

The `init` is returning an `NSMutableArray` object. Sometimes though, an `init` method could return a parent class, like `NSArray` in this example. Using the `id` type allows any object to be returned.